# Update to Yosemite: will I be able to sync iCal to iOS6/7?

Tags: icloud, macos, upgrade, ios

I have Mountain Lion and want to upgrade to **Yosemite**.
I need to use iCal on my old iPad (iOs6).
I heard Yosemite asks you to update to iCloud Drive (that can't be installed on iOs6/7) and that you won't be able to sync some apps until you update. 
**Will iCal sync on Yosemite if you don't upgrade to icloud drive?** If not, should I update to Maverick instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually updated and checked myself, and the answer to my question yes: even if you don't update to iCloud Drive, iCal keeps working and syncs on your devices connected to the old iCloud.